# Pillow icon group sizes issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

windows 11 pro
OS Version: 10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
python 3.12.0
pillow 10.2.0

code:

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Vars:
    sizes = [(16, 16), (192, 192), (96, 96), (32, 32), (64, 64), (128, 128), (48, 48), (256, 256), (24, 24)]
    formats = ["bmp", "dds", "dib", "eps", "icns", "im", "jpeg", "png", "ppm", "sgi", "tiff", "webp", "tga", "pcx",
               "msp", "gif", "ico"]


def convert_image(data: bytes, output_type: str) -> bytes | None:
    if output_type.lower() not in Vars.formats:
        return
    if output_type.lower() == "ico":
        with BytesIO() as output:
            with Image.open(data) as img:
                img.save(output, format='ICO', quality=100, sizes=Vars.sizes, subsampling=0, bitmap_format="bmp")
                with Image.open(output) as check:
                    print(check.info)
            return output.getvalue()
    with BytesIO() as output:
        with Image.open(data) as img:
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            img.save(output, format=output_type)
        return output.getvalue()
```

output:

```
{'sizes': {(96, 91), (48, 46), (24, 23), (32, 30), (192, 183), (128, 122), (64, 61), (256, 244), (16, 15)}}
```

issue:
the specified sizes are being ignored when saving the icon.
i made sure i have the newest pil version, also tested with third party tools that getting desired icon group sizes with my given image is possible.

the image is a random image from my pc i just picked for testing

any help will be greatly appricated! my current solution is to load a C# dll via clr but i would prefer to use purely python when possible.

the code is the entire file, at no point did i somehow modify Vars.sizes.

i tried upgrading the Pillow version, but already have the latest version

actual code i ran

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Vars:
    sizes = [(16, 16), (192, 192), (96, 96), (32, 32), (64, 64), (128, 128), (48, 48), (256, 256), (24, 24)]
    formats = ["bmp", "dds", "dib", "eps", "icns", "im", "jpeg", "png", "ppm", "sgi", "tiff", "webp", "tga", "pcx",
               "msp", "gif", "ico"]


def convert_image(data: bytes, output_type: str) -> bytes | None:
    if output_type.lower() not in Vars.formats:
        return
    if output_type.lower() == "ico":
        with BytesIO() as output:
            with Image.open(data) as img:
                img.save(output, format='ICO', quality=100, sizes=Vars.sizes, subsampling=0, bitmap_format="bmp")
                with Image.open(output) as check:
                    print(check.info)
            return output.getvalue()
    with BytesIO() as output:
        with Image.open(data) as img:
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            img.save(output, format=output_type)
        return output.getvalue()

with open(r"c:\path\to\image.png", "rb") as input_image:
   data = input_image.read()
returned_icon = convert_image(data, "ico")
with open(r"c:\path\to\output_icon.ico", "wb") as outputted_icon:
   outputted_icon.write(returned_icon)
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and show the actual code you ran.

Comment: its not any diffrent than the one i pasted, but i did.

Comment: It is different - your original code didn't actually call any functions, or show what files you opened or how.

Comment: How are you verifying that the sizes are ignored?  The output you show looks reasonable.

Comment: How did you get on with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you think the problem is here. If I change your code to the expected *"minimal, complete and verifiable"* format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Create 256x244 image
im = Image.new('RGB', (256,244))

# List of icon sizes we want
sizes = [(16, 16), (192, 192), (96, 96), (32, 32), (64, 64), (128, 128), (48, 48), (256, 256), (24, 24)]

# Save icons
im.save('result.ico', format='ICO', sizes=sizes, bitmap_format="bmp")
```

I get a file `result.ico` whose contents I can check with **ImageMagick** and see the same as you got:

```
identify result.ico
```

**Output**

```
result.ico[0] ICO 16x15 16x15+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[1] ICO 24x23 24x23+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[2] ICO 32x31 32x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[3] ICO 48x46 48x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[4] ICO 64x61 64x61+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[5] ICO 96x92 96x92+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[6] ICO 128x122 128x122+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[7] ICO 192x183 192x183+0+0 8-bit sRGB 268430B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

---

If I start off with a ***square*** image of 256x256, or resize, or pad the original one to square, I get the sizes I assume you were expecting:

```
result.ico[0] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
result.ico[1] ICO 24x24 24x24+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
result.ico[2] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
result.ico[3] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
result.ico[4] ICO 64x64 64x64+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
result.ico[5] ICO 96x96 96x96+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
result.ico[6] ICO 128x128 128x128+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
result.ico[7] ICO 192x192 192x192+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
result.ico[8] ICO 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 483006B 0.000u 0:00.001
```